# Connect one Android device with two bluetooth speakers simultaneously

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, speaker

I was wondering if it's possible to connect a single Android device with one bluetooth chips inside to two (or more) bluetooth speakers simultaneously, and if the answer is affirmative, every type of speakers or some models  in particular?
Thanks for the answers

Comment: AFAIK you can connect to up to 7 devices according to the Bluetooth spec but the audio pipeline will only allow you to play audio to one device. Samsung has added a feature to selectively play audio from one app only on an external device but so far that's all I know of.